# Channelizing logs on Bind 8

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I am using the following channel clause in my named.conf,

```
logging {
channel named_log {
file "logs-remote/bind.log";
severity dynamic;
print-category yes;
print-severity yes;
print-time yes;
};

channel query_log {
     file "logs-remote/query.log";
     severity dynamic;
     print-severity yes;
     print-time yes;
};

include "logging_category_remote.conf";
};
```

When I run the dig command,

```
dig gcs.net
```

the query log is written in bind.log and not query.log, I want them properly channelized as expressed in the said channel clause, any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Bind **8**, really?

Comment: @Håkan Wow, I didn't even notice that. I really *am* sick.

Comment: Yeah Bind 8, clients man, clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't define a category in that snippet.

```
category queries { query_log; };
```

All the `channel query_log` statement does is define a logging target named `query_log`. If it is present in `logging_category_remote.conf`, please share the contents of that file.

Comment: Oh yes. That file had all the other categories defined except for queries, thanks a lot!